# How to use stabilizers to simulate the circuit?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-circuit, stabilizer-state

Sorry for this easy questions. That is a simple textbook question but I don't know how to solve it.

I have the following circuit:

[image]

The question was "use stabilizers to simulate the circuit"

My first question is: what is the difference between solving this circuit and solving it **with stabilizers**?
How can I use stabilizers to simulate the circuit? What will be the stabilizers corresponding to the output?
(I first wanted to write what stabilize the state = $|0\rangle|+\rangle$. It should be two qubit Pauli like $XX$ but I am not sure)

Comment: Probably need a bit more context to actually answer this. This is a Clifford circuit, and stabilizers play a role in simulating Clifford circuits, so maybe that's what this is referring to?